# Rounding prices in WooCoommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding

I'm having the following issue when I'm trying to round up prices in WC:
Product A has '160.4839' as a regular price. I'm adding tax on top of this (which is 24%). The total price that should be shown (including tax) should 199.00.
Product B has '96.7000' as a regular price. The tax on top of that is 24%. The price that should be shown is 120.00 (currently it's 119.90 what it's being displayed).
And this is my round function located in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter('wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ){
    return round($price, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

I do realise that my problem lies somewhere with the decimals, but I can't get round() right. How could I achieve the above result? It's been driving me mental.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update the function with this :

```
function round_price_product( $price ){
    return ceil( $price );
}
```

Check if it's working.

Comment: thanks man. It's not what I've expected, as it's adding 1.00 on top of the wanted result (so Produtct A is 200.00 instead of 199.00 and Product B is 121.00 instead of 120.00). Any idea why?

Comment: can you print the $price value inside the function and paste here what it is?

Comment: I did a print($price) and this is what I got for product B
`96.7000 96.7000 121.00lei
96.7000 96.7000 96.7000 120.28 119.91 96.7000 96.7000 96.7000 96.7000 120.28 119.91 96.7000 96.7000 96.7000 96.7000 120.28 119.91 96.7000 96.7000 96.7000 96.7000`

Comment: Just try to use round($price) without any parameters, if it works?

Comment: return round($price) returns the correct value for Product B (120.00), but product A is 198.00 (when it should be 199.00)

Comment: @Seb As per your question you want to use the round function with `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` that means  "Round val up to precision decimal places away from zero" and same is for the ceil. it will be give you the nearest integer up. Now it up to you what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87244/discussion-between-seb-and-toretto).

Answer (score 0):

After loads of searching left and right I came to the conclusion that prices with decimals in WooCommerce are a real pain. So my final solution was disabling them entirely from WooCommerce's admin panel.